# Is there any special property about incomplete beta function $B(x;1-x,x)$?

Tags: beta-function

guys,

I encountered a function like
$$
f(x) = B(x;1-x,x)
$$
where $B(\cdot)$ is the incomplete beta function and input $0 < x < 1$ is some positive small real value close to zero . I want to evaluate the value of $f(x)$ and its derivative. I am wondering is there any special property that I can make use of to approximate the function.

Thanks

Comment: Wolfram alpha may have some useful info: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=beta%5Bx,1-x,x%5D

Answer (score 0):

Using [**these $\text B_z(a,b)$ identities**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28x%2C+998%2F999+-+x%2C+x%29%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-x%29+%28%28-1%29%5E%28998%2F999%29+beta%281%2F999%2C+998%2F999+-+x%29+%2B+beta%281%2Fx%2C+1%2F999%2C+x%29%29). There is this special proprety:

$$\text B_x(1-x,x)=(-1)^{-x}\left(\pi(\cot(\pi x)+i)-\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x\Phi\left(1-\frac1x,1,x\right)\right)$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28x%2C+1+-+x%2C+x%29%2C%28-1%29%5E%28-x%29+%28%CF%80+%28i+%2B+cot%28%CF%80+x%29%29-+%28%281-1%2Fx%29%5Ex+lerch%281-1%2Fx%2C1%2Cx%29%29%29) with [Lerch Phi $\Phi(z,s,a)$](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjcwda_k-P7AhVcinIEHR3KAnIQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Freference.wolfram.com%2Flanguage%2Fref%2FLerchPhi.html&usg=AOvVaw08wKZuirPicd-10vpwIbRa)

Now only 2 arguments of $\Phi(z,s,a)$ have variables instead of all three of $\text B_z(a,b)$. The derivative of $\text B_x(1-x,x)$ has [generalized hypergeometric functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddx+beta%28x%2C1-x%2Cx%29), but differentiating the right hand side uses simpler functions:

$$\frac d{dx} (-1)^{-x}\left(\pi(\cot(\pi x)+i)-\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x\Phi\left(1-\frac1x,1,x\right)\right)=\left(\frac1x-1\right)^x\left(\pi(-1)^{\frac52}\Phi+\Phi-\ln\left(1-\frac1x\right)\Phi+\frac1{1-x}+\pi^2\left((-1)^\frac32\cot(\pi x)-\csc^2(\pi x)+1\right)\right),\Phi=\Phi\left(1-\frac1x,1,x\right)$$